# Upload custom html and website files to godaddy

Tags: html, hosting

I have bought a GoDaddy server hosting subscription for my website but when I explore the website options menu there isn't any way for me to upload my own html and website files.

I am new to this entire hosting business, any answers are welcome.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either [use the File Manager built into your hosting CPanel](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manage-files-in-my-linux-hosting-account-12426), which is essentially your admin panel for your website, or set up an FTP connection through a program like Filezilla that allows you to remotely access your website's folders.  For simpler websites, the File Manager is probably sufficient, but you'll want to explore FTP for anything complex or large.